# Why can't I flag a question with open bounty as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It is impossible to flag question with open bounties, and I have a vague understanding why this rule is around in general. **However, I have seen quite a few users using a bounty as way to shield their question which would otherwise be flagged pretty fast (and correctly) as duplicate.** I am most worried about this kind of flag since such duplicate questions are most probably being answered. In my humble opinion, this leads to a large number of questions with answers for the very same topic and eventually decrease the overall quality by this branching. Do others share this concern?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions Can't VTC as Too Broad (or "needs more focus" if you prefer) either, even though such questions aren't infrequently overly broad

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I am not sure what you are saying - I understand that the linked question is similar?

Comment: I should have put a bounty on this very question here `*just*kidding*` - things are just too fast here at meta. @yivi: Thanks for the hint, even though I am not totally convinced by the answer you linked.

Comment: @B--rian convinced or not - that is why the rules were set,  The bounty has to be removed and refunded before it can be closed and that can only be done by a moderator manually.

Comment: 2 days that needed to add bounty is not "pretty fast" in my book... Not sure how one would use bounty to shield new question from closing as duplicate...

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Very valid point, that a bounty cannot immediately be offered. I buy that argument.